# How to create lines on background like in Google Play app?

Tags: android

There was a nice article/tutorial how to create a background with lines at the certain angles using `shapes` or `lines`... or some `drawings` at the end. Does anybody know such? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it by xml like [this](https://blob-s-docs.googlegroups.com/docs/OgAAACUiML83LMfFVJuBtKTMHrCdp2mT1q0xrrQm4SE4qBBra2T_PCCWQJLrBdV4Pz0_6pDyiw0FSXsvqxJ0D0YqrEwA15jOjGmXXi2uJk-BEaa2plde4cVwmb8r)

[refer page 27:](https://docs.google.com/present/view?id=dfp6vxvn_47dcz63pjj)

[image]

Comment: Yeah, this is what I seen. I thought there is no images at all. Anyway, that's what I was looking for, thank you, Kumar.

Answer (score 0):

There are few website which generate stripes online with preview: [stripegenerator.com](http://www.stripegenerator.com/) and [stripemania.com](http://www.stripemania.com/)

Comment: Meaning how to make it without pictures.